# Is it possible to add an attribute to a variable in python?

Tags: python

I want to know if it is possible to add an attribute to a variable in python. For example create the variable `a=45` and then add as a label or property something like `units=m/s`

Thank you.

Comment: You could make a class that has properties like `value`(45) and `units`(m/s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no such thing as a structure in python as in C, we could implement it by using either a class or a dictionary.

class method:

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 25
        self.unit = "m/s"
```

Dictionary method:

```
var1 = {'value': 25, 'unit': 'm/s'}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't nested list also an option?

Answer (score 2):

Since, it is an arbitrary data type you are wanting to implement, it'd be more helpful through classes. By doing that, you are free to do mathematical operations on the instances

The template would be:

```
 class Speed(object):
    def __init__(self, value, unit="m/s"):
        self.magnitude = value
        self.unit = unit
```

and you'd like to implement mathemtaical operation using methods in the class

Answer (score 2):

A straight `int` or `float` object does not support attributes.

With Python 3+, you might consider using function [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107):

```
>>> def kinetic_energy(m:'in KG', v:'in M/S')->'Joules': 
>>>    return 1/2*m*v**2
...            
>>> x=kinetic_energy(3,4)
>>> print(x, kinetic_energy.__annotations__['return'])     
24.0 Joules
>>> kinetic_energy.__annotations__
{'m': 'in KG', 'v': 'in M/S', 'return': 'Joules'}
```

Comment: Function attributes are also available in v2.1+.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of the variable. If it's an instance of a custom class, then you probably can, but if it's an instance of a built-in or extension class, then whether you can do it depends on the implementation.

You can work around this in many cases by just deriving your own class from the one given — for example:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

i = MyInt(21)
i.units= 'm/s'

print(i.units)  # --> m/s
print(i*2)      # --> 42
```

This approach has the advantage that for the most part you can use a derived class instance anywhere the base class was accepted/expected — as illustrated by the last line which uses`i`in an arithmetic expression. Note however, that without some additional methods being added to the derived class, the result of the expression`i*2`will be an`int`, not a`MyInt`.

For the special case of just wanting to a simple single attribute like units, you could derive different classes representing the possibilites, and then use`isinstance()`to determine a value's units:

```
class MetersPerSecond(float):
    pass

v = MetersPerSecond(2.3)
print('isinstance(v, MetersPerSecond): {}'.format(
        isinstance(v, 
                   MetersPerSecond)))  # --> isinstance(v, MetersPerSecond): True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make class with attributes as units and values.
Another possible solution to this can be using dictionary

`{a: 'm/s', b: 'm^2'}`

Or two lists if duplicate values can occur

`myVars = [a, b, 100, d]
myUnits = ['m/s', 'm^2', 's', 'm']`

Then myResult = str(myVars[0]) + str(myUnits[0])